# How to set alpha channel color for image?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I use an old software which can't read some gif formats. I have an image which this software reads perfectly. Here is part of `magick identify` output for this image:

```
Image:
  Filename: af4a4cd07bf8bf2e0a32ac795e3f688313992199.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 600x225+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
    Alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 135000
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 210.766 (0.826532)
      median: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 79.6865 (0.312496)
      kurtosis: 0.391611
      skewness: -1.42784
      entropy: 0.34599
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 202.466 (0.793984)
      median: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 88.9531 (0.348836)
      kurtosis: -0.234975
      skewness: -1.25805
      entropy: 0.353168
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 192.395 (0.75449)
      median: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 99.826 (0.391474)
      kurtosis: -0.681473
      skewness: -1.07706
      entropy: 0.353545
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 76.857 (0.3014)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 117.011 (0.458868)
      kurtosis: -1.25074
      skewness: 0.865602
      entropy: 0.882996
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 170.621 (0.669101)
      median: 191.25 (0.75)
      standard deviation: 96.3692 (0.377918)
      kurtosis: -1.44093
      skewness: -0.663742
      entropy: 0.483925
  Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0)   #FFFFFF00
  Colors: 256
  Histogram:
    3519: (0,0,0,255) #000000FF black
    67: (2,2,2,255) #020202FF srgba(2,2,2,1)
    3: (2,2,6,255) #020206FF srgba(2,2,6,1)
    1: (2,6,6,255) #020606FF srgba(2,6,6,1)
    66: (4,85,5,255) #045505FF srgba(4,85,5,1)
    85: (4,117,5,255) #047505FF srgba(4,117,5,1)
    180: (5,150,5,255) #059605FF srgba(5,150,5,1)
    20: (6,2,6,255) #060206FF srgba(6,2,6,1)
    3: (6,4,12,255) #06040CFF srgba(6,4,12,1)
    13: (6,7,2,255) #060702FF srgba(6,7,2,1)
    32: (7,2,2,255) #070202FF srgba(7,2,2,1)
    81: (7,6,6,255) #070606FF srgba(7,6,6,1)
    39: (8,61,8,255) #083D08FF srgba(8,61,8,1)
    6: (9,11,14,255) #090B0EFF srgba(9,11,14,1)
    21: (9,38,5,255) #092605FF srgba(9,38,5,1)
    2: (12,6,12,255) #0C060CFF srgba(12,6,12,1)
    105: (12,12,11,255) #0C0C0BFF srgba(12,12,11,1)
    68: (13,5,2,255) #0D0502FF srgba(13,5,2,1)
    28: (13,16,18,255) #0D1012FF srgba(13,16,18,1)
    119: (18,12,7,255) #120C07FF srgba(18,12,7,1)
    105: (21,18,15,255) #15120FFF srgba(21,18,15,1)
    58: (22,22,22,255) #161616FF srgba(22,22,22,1)
    201: (26,8,2,255) #1A0802FF srgba(26,8,2,1)
    156: (28,23,19,255) #1C1713FF srgba(28,23,19,1)
    18: (28,86,29,255) #1C561DFF srgba(28,86,29,1)
    265: (29,17,7,255) #1D1107FF srgba(29,17,7,1)
    69: (29,28,28,255) #1D1C1CFF srgba(29,28,28,1)
    63: (32,34,34,255) #202222FF srgba(32,34,34,1)
    207: (36,13,2,255) #240D02FF srgba(36,13,2,1)
    199: (36,19,5,255) #241305FF srgba(36,19,5,1)
    118: (36,22,11,255) #24160BFF srgba(36,22,11,1)
    109: (36,27,16,255) #241B10FF srgba(36,27,16,1)
    125: (36,28,24,255) #241C18FF srgba(36,28,24,1)
    145: (42,22,10,255) #2A160AFF srgba(42,22,10,1)
    38: (42,31,35,255) #2A1F23FF srgba(42,31,35,1)
    123: (42,40,38,255) #2A2826FF srgba(42,40,38,1)
    76: (43,29,20,255) #2B1D14FF srgba(43,29,20,1)
    142: (43,35,27,255) #2B231BFF srgba(43,35,27,1)
    196: (44,20,3,255) #2C1403FF srgba(44,20,3,1)
    100: (45,26,6,255) #2D1A06FF srgba(45,26,6,1)
    108: (45,26,11,255) #2D1A0BFF srgba(45,26,11,1)
    22: (48,14,2,255) #300E02FF srgba(48,14,2,1)
    9: (48,22,13,255) #30160DFF srgba(48,22,13,1)
    69: (48,35,21,255) #302315FF srgba(48,35,21,1)
    82: (48,45,45,255) #302D2DFF srgba(48,45,45,1)
    54: (49,30,15,255) #311E0FFF srgba(49,30,15,1)
    50: (50,26,10,255) #321A0AFF srgba(50,26,10,1)
    61: (50,30,10,255) #321E0AFF srgba(50,30,10,1)
    66: (50,50,50,255) #323232FF srgba(50,50,50,1)
    121: (51,21,2,255) #331502FF srgba(51,21,2,1)
    210: (52,26,5,255) #341A05FF srgba(52,26,5,1)
    125: (53,40,29,255) #35281DFF srgba(53,40,29,1)
    20: (53,40,55,255) #352837FF srgba(53,40,55,1)
    208: (53,44,37,255) #352C25FF srgba(53,44,37,1)
    7: (53,108,53,255) #356C35FF srgba(53,108,53,1)
    3: (54,26,10,255) #361A0AFF srgba(54,26,10,1)
    4862: (54,29,8,255) #361D08FF srgba(54,29,8,1)
    144: (54,30,10,255) #361E0AFF srgba(54,30,10,1)
    15: (56,29,20,255) #381D14FF srgba(56,29,20,1)
    88: (56,37,21,255) #382515FF srgba(56,37,21,1)
    111: (57,56,54,255) #393836FF srgba(57,56,54,1)
    3: (58,22,10,255) #3A160AFF srgba(58,22,10,1)
    4: (58,26,11,255) #3A1A0BFF srgba(58,26,11,1)
    257: (58,30,6,255) #3A1E06FF srgba(58,30,6,1)
    146: (58,30,10,255) #3A1E0AFF srgba(58,30,10,1)
    157: (59,50,44,255) #3B322CFF srgba(59,50,44,1)
    67: (60,24,2,255) #3C1802FF srgba(60,24,2,1)
    145: (60,34,11,255) #3C220BFF srgba(60,34,11,1)
    77: (61,49,31,255) #3D311FFF srgba(61,49,31,1)
    30: (63,30,5,255) #3F1E05FF srgba(63,30,5,1)
    69: (63,58,63,255) #3F3A3FFF srgba(63,58,63,1)
    68: (64,48,39,255) #403027FF srgba(64,48,39,1)
    8: (65,26,13,255) #411A0DFF srgba(65,26,13,1)
    59: (65,40,19,255) #412813FF srgba(65,40,19,1)
    26: (66,33,15,255) #42210FFF srgba(66,33,15,1)
    82: (67,44,26,255) #432C1AFF srgba(67,44,26,1)
    37: (67,48,56,255) #433038FF srgba(67,48,56,1)
    93: (67,67,67,255) #434343FF srgba(67,67,67,1)
    159: (68,37,12,255) #44250CFF srgba(68,37,12,1)
    121: (68,55,45,255) #44372DFF srgba(68,55,45,1)
    53: (69,34,5,255) #452205FF srgba(69,34,5,1)
    91: (69,54,35,255) #453623FF srgba(69,54,35,1)
    73: (70,29,2,255) #461D02FF srgba(70,29,2,1)
    115: (70,60,53,255) #463C35FF srgba(70,60,53,1)
    77: (74,66,61,255) #4A423DFF srgba(74,66,61,1)
    98: (74,72,70,255) #4A4846FF srgba(74,72,70,1)
    71: (75,37,12,255) #4B250CFF srgba(75,37,12,1)
    58: (75,47,25,255) #4B2F19FF srgba(75,47,25,1)
    140: (76,42,14,255) #4C2A0EFF srgba(76,42,14,1)
    99: (76,63,41,255) #4C3F29FF srgba(76,63,41,1)
    115: (78,35,3,255) #4E2303FF srgba(78,35,3,1)
    120: (79,65,53,255) #4F4135FF srgba(79,65,53,1)
    93: (79,77,77,255) #4F4D4DFF srgba(79,77,77,1)
    51: (80,53,32,255) #503520FF srgba(80,53,32,1)
    45: (81,46,18,255) #512E12FF srgba(81,46,18,1)
    52: (81,59,75,255) #513B4BFF srgba(81,59,75,1)
    63: (82,83,82,255) #525352FF srgba(82,83,82,1)
    99: (83,42,12,255) #532A0CFF srgba(83,42,12,1)
    12: (83,55,22,255) #533716FF srgba(83,55,22,1)
    6: (84,37,16,255) #542510FF srgba(84,37,16,1)
    21: (84,50,23,255) #543217FF srgba(84,50,23,1)
    146: (85,46,14,255) #552E0EFF srgba(85,46,14,1)
    36: (85,60,37,255) #553C25FF srgba(85,60,37,1)
    80: (85,70,44,255) #55462CFF srgba(85,70,44,1)
    131: (85,72,60,255) #55483CFF srgba(85,72,60,1)
    114: (86,39,4,255) #562704FF srgba(86,39,4,1)
    511: (86,46,18,255) #562E12FF srgba(86,46,18,1)
    163: (86,50,18,255) #563212FF srgba(86,50,18,1)
    30: (86,55,30,255) #56371EFF srgba(86,55,30,1)
    55: (86,73,68,255) #564944FF srgba(86,73,68,1)
    48: (87,64,85,255) #574055FF srgba(87,64,85,1)
    8: (89,42,18,255) #592A12FF srgba(89,42,18,1)
    53: (89,82,76,255) #59524CFF srgba(89,82,76,1)
    97: (89,88,87,255) #595857FF srgba(89,88,87,1)
    128: (90,46,14,255) #5A2E0EFF srgba(90,46,14,1)
    9: (90,121,90,255) #5A795AFF srgba(90,121,90,1)
    260: (91,50,18,255) #5B3212FF srgba(91,50,18,1)
    11: (91,54,25,255) #5B3619FF srgba(91,54,25,1)
    22: (92,60,28,255) #5C3C1CFF srgba(92,60,28,1)
    70: (92,76,47,255) #5C4C2FFF srgba(92,76,47,1)
    99: (93,79,66,255) #5D4F42FF srgba(93,79,66,1)
    125: (94,50,14,255) #5E320EFF srgba(94,50,14,1)
    32: (94,54,19,255) #5E3613FF srgba(94,54,19,1)
    111: (95,94,93,255) #5F5E5DFF srgba(95,94,93,1)
    121: (96,44,4,255) #602C04FF srgba(96,44,4,1)
    36: (96,64,36,255) #604024FF srgba(96,64,36,1)
    970: (97,82,69,255) #615245FF srgba(97,82,69,1)
    127: (98,82,70,255) #625246FF srgba(98,82,70,1)
    79: (98,83,51,255) #625333FF srgba(98,83,51,1)
    156: (98,86,70,255) #625646FF srgba(98,86,70,1)
    20: (99,62,29,255) #633E1DFF srgba(99,62,29,1)
    59: (99,72,94,255) #63485EFF srgba(99,72,94,1)
    36: (100,84,60,255) #64543CFF srgba(100,84,60,1)
    52: (100,92,84,255) #645C54FF srgba(100,92,84,1)
    124: (101,54,16,255) #653610FF srgba(101,54,16,1)
    7: (101,58,21,255) #653A15FF srgba(101,58,21,1)
    8: (102,82,68,255) #665244FF srgba(102,82,68,1)
    95: (102,86,70,255) #665646FF srgba(102,86,70,1)
    97: (102,86,74,255) #66564AFF srgba(102,86,74,1)
    97: (102,100,99,255) #666463FF srgba(102,100,99,1)
    33: (103,68,38,255) #674426FF srgba(103,68,38,1)
    109: (104,49,7,255) #683107FF srgba(104,49,7,1)
    10: (105,58,23,255) #693A17FF srgba(105,58,23,1)
    24: (105,74,50,255) #694A32FF srgba(105,74,50,1)
    28: (106,54,18,255) #6A3612FF srgba(106,54,18,1)
    33: (106,58,18,255) #6A3A12FF srgba(106,58,18,1)
    89: (106,89,54,255) #6A5936FF srgba(106,89,54,1)
    13: (107,86,75,255) #6B564BFF srgba(107,86,75,1)
    84: (107,91,75,255) #6B5B4BFF srgba(107,91,75,1)
    131: (108,54,11,255) #6C360BFF srgba(108,54,11,1)
    6348: (108,57,16,255) #6C3910FF srgba(108,57,16,1)
    27: (108,67,33,255) #6C4321FF srgba(108,67,33,1)
    56: (108,95,60,255) #6C5F3CFF srgba(108,95,60,1)
    15: (109,62,24,255) #6D3E18FF srgba(109,62,24,1)
    3: (110,57,22,255) #6E3916FF srgba(110,57,22,1)
    563: (110,58,18,255) #6E3A12FF srgba(110,58,18,1)
    40: (110,62,18,255) #6E3E12FF srgba(110,62,18,1)
    82: (110,80,107,255) #6E506BFF srgba(110,80,107,1)
    56: (113,74,39,255) #714A27FF srgba(113,74,39,1)
    87: (113,110,110,255) #716E6EFF srgba(113,110,110,1)
    258: (114,58,14,255) #723A0EFF srgba(114,58,14,1)
    51: (114,58,18,255) #723A12FF srgba(114,58,18,1)
    513: (114,62,18,255) #723E12FF srgba(114,62,18,1)
    13: (115,86,62,255) #73563EFF srgba(115,86,62,1)
    74: (115,105,90,255) #73695AFF srgba(115,105,90,1)
    12: (116,62,23,255) #743E17FF srgba(116,62,23,1)
    110: (117,99,59,255) #75633BFF srgba(117,99,59,1)
    68: (117,101,72,255) #756548FF srgba(117,101,72,1)
    143: (118,62,18,255) #763E12FF srgba(118,62,18,1)
    18: (118,67,25,255) #764319FF srgba(118,67,25,1)
    54: (120,80,44,255) #78502CFF srgba(120,80,44,1)
    83: (124,92,122,255) #7C5C7AFF srgba(124,92,122,1)
    37: (125,66,19,255) #7D4213FF srgba(125,66,19,1)
    148: (125,106,65,255) #7D6A41FF srgba(125,106,65,1)
    108: (125,125,125,255) #7D7D7DFF grey49
    59: (129,54,4,255) #813604FF srgba(129,54,4,1)
    86: (131,89,51,255) #835933FF srgba(131,89,51,1)
    78: (131,117,92,255) #83755CFF srgba(131,117,92,1)
    181: (133,114,69,255) #857245FF srgba(133,114,69,1)
    11: (136,76,29,255) #884C1DFF srgba(136,76,29,1)
    99: (140,102,138,255) #8C668AFF srgba(140,102,138,1)
    172: (142,122,74,255) #8E7A4AFF srgba(142,122,74,1)
    62: (144,63,5,255) #903F05FF srgba(144,63,5,1)
    79: (145,146,148,255) #919294FF srgba(145,146,148,1)
    57: (146,132,104,255) #928468FF srgba(146,132,104,1)
    194: (152,131,79,255) #98834FFF srgba(152,131,79,1)
    64: (161,69,3,255) #A14503FF srgba(161,69,3,1)
    187: (161,139,84,255) #A18B54FF srgba(161,139,84,1)
    54: (163,163,166,255) #A3A3A6FF srgba(163,163,166,1)
    152: (165,121,163,255) #A579A3FF srgba(165,121,163,1)
    188: (171,147,87,255) #AB9357FF srgba(171,147,87,1)
    126: (177,153,94,255) #B1995EFF srgba(177,153,94,1)
    64: (182,183,186,255) #B6B7BAFF srgba(182,183,186,1)
    65: (185,79,2,255) #B94F02FF srgba(185,79,2,1)
    134: (185,159,91,255) #B99F5BFF srgba(185,159,91,1)
    105: (189,164,99,255) #BDA463FF srgba(189,164,99,1)
    4: (190,176,148,255) #BEB094FF srgba(190,176,148,1)
    338: (196,143,189,255) #C48FBDFF srgba(196,143,189,1)
    51: (197,171,93,255) #C5AB5DFF srgba(197,171,93,1)
    109: (198,171,102,255) #C6AB66FF srgba(198,171,102,1)
    63: (203,178,107,255) #CBB26BFF srgba(203,178,107,1)
    80: (203,204,209,255) #CBCCD1FF srgba(203,204,209,1)
    95: (207,177,103,255) #CFB167FF srgba(207,177,103,1)
    144: (209,95,2,255) #D15F02FF srgba(209,95,2,1)
    40: (210,189,114,255) #D2BD72FF srgba(210,189,114,1)
    110: (212,183,106,255) #D4B76AFF srgba(212,183,106,1)
    120: (219,188,110,255) #DBBC6EFF srgba(219,188,110,1)
    59: (220,196,115,255) #DCC473FF srgba(220,196,115,1)
    184: (222,163,214,255) #DEA3D6FF srgba(222,163,214,1)
    68: (226,192,115,255) #E2C073FF srgba(226,192,115,1)
    59: (228,199,111,255) #E4C76FFF srgba(228,199,111,1)
    59: (230,208,123,255) #E6D07BFF srgba(230,208,123,1)
    88: (230,230,234,255) #E6E6EAFF srgba(230,230,234,1)
    130: (232,200,119,255) #E8C877FF srgba(232,200,119,1)
    7: (235,223,135,255) #EBDF87FF srgba(235,223,135,1)
    30: (237,216,127,255) #EDD87FFF srgba(237,216,127,1)
    59: (238,206,117,255) #EECE75FF srgba(238,206,117,1)
    87: (240,205,123,255) #F0CD7BFF srgba(240,205,123,1)
    71: (243,211,125,255) #F3D37DFF srgba(243,211,125,1)
    29: (245,214,130,255) #F5D682FF srgba(245,214,130,1)
    34: (245,219,125,255) #F5DB7DFF srgba(245,219,125,1)
    31: (245,220,131,255) #F5DC83FF srgba(245,220,131,1)
    44: (246,207,122,255) #F6CF7AFF srgba(246,207,122,1)
    2: (246,222,138,255) #F6DE8AFF srgba(246,222,138,1)
    9: (246,228,133,255) #F6E485FF srgba(246,228,133,1)
    1: (246,238,142,255) #F6EE8EFF srgba(246,238,142,1)
    22: (247,213,121,255) #F7D579FF srgba(247,213,121,1)
    33: (248,214,126,255) #F8D67EFF srgba(248,214,126,1)
    13: (249,229,138,255) #F9E58AFF srgba(249,229,138,1)
    42: (250,210,126,255) #FAD27EFF srgba(250,210,126,1)
    50: (250,218,130,255) #FADA82FF srgba(250,218,130,1)
    1: (250,218,134,255) #FADA86FF srgba(250,218,134,1)
    22: (250,222,134,255) #FADE86FF srgba(250,222,134,1)
    21: (250,223,130,255) #FADF82FF srgba(250,223,130,1)
    2: (252,212,118,255) #FCD476FF srgba(252,212,118,1)
    36: (253,219,126,255) #FDDB7EFF srgba(253,219,126,1)
    32: (253,234,134,255) #FDEA86FF srgba(253,234,134,1)
    144: (254,210,126,255) #FED27EFF srgba(254,210,126,1)
    3062: (254,213,127,255) #FED57FFF srgba(254,213,127,1)
    15: (254,214,126,255) #FED67EFF srgba(254,214,126,1)
    90: (254,214,130,255) #FED682FF srgba(254,214,130,1)
    8: (254,217,122,255) #FED97AFF srgba(254,217,122,1)
    504: (254,218,130,255) #FEDA82FF srgba(254,218,130,1)
    5: (254,218,134,255) #FEDA86FF srgba(254,218,134,1)
    1: (254,220,140,255) #FEDC8CFF srgba(254,220,140,1)
    346: (254,222,130,255) #FEDE82FF srgba(254,222,130,1)
    196: (254,222,134,255) #FEDE86FF srgba(254,222,134,1)
    10: (254,226,126,255) #FEE27EFF srgba(254,226,126,1)
    375: (254,227,134,255) #FEE386FF srgba(254,227,134,1)
    218: (254,229,138,255) #FEE58AFF srgba(254,229,138,1)
    149: (254,235,140,255) #FEEB8CFF srgba(254,235,140,1)
    36: (254,242,141,255) #FEF28DFF srgba(254,242,141,1)
    27: (254,242,146,255) #FEF292FF srgba(254,242,146,1)
    20: (254,249,149,255) #FEF995FF srgba(254,249,149,1)
    277: (254,254,255,255) #FEFEFFFF srgba(254,254,255,1)
    94311: (255,255,255,0) #FFFFFF00 srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Colormap entries: 256
  Colormap:
    0: (0,0,0,1) #000000FF black
    1: (254,213,127,1) #FED57FFF srgba(254,213,127,1)
...
```

And there is a GIF that this software can't read:

```
Image:
  Filename: test.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 942x807+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
    Alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 760194
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 191 (0.74902)
      mean: 114.081 (0.447376)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 70.4866 (0.276418)
      kurtosis: -0.990858
      skewness: -0.768517
      entropy: 0.483082
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 125.103 (0.4906)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 85.1152 (0.333785)
      kurtosis: -0.88958
      skewness: -0.173986
      entropy: 0.475376
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 125.103 (0.4906)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 85.1152 (0.333785)
      kurtosis: -0.88958
      skewness: -0.173986
      entropy: 0.475376
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 191.036 (0.749163)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 110.541 (0.433495)
      kurtosis: -0.678534
      skewness: -1.14955
      entropy: 0.812602
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 138.831 (0.544435)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 87.8146 (0.344371)
      kurtosis: -1.16615
      skewness: -0.29028
      entropy: 0.561609
  Alpha: none   #00000000
  Colors: 60
  Histogram:
    190685: (0,0,0,0) #00000000 none
    730: (53,53,53,255) #353535FF srgba(53,53,53,1)
    984: (59,59,59,255) #3B3B3BFF grey23
    580: (67,67,67,255) #434343FF srgba(67,67,67,1)
    388: (75,75,75,255) #4B4B4BFF srgba(75,75,75,1)
    627: (83,83,83,255) #535353FF srgba(83,83,83,1)
    18672: (93,93,93,255) #5D5D5DFF srgba(93,93,93,1)
    32777: (99,99,99,255) #636363FF grey39
    14: (103,105,105,255) #676969FF srgba(103,105,105,1)
    18209: (108,108,108,255) #6C6C6CFF srgba(108,108,108,1)
    393: (109,114,114,255) #6D7272FF srgba(109,114,114,1)
    15818: (115,115,115,255) #737373FF grey45
    19: (116,124,124,255) #747C7CFF srgba(116,124,124,1)
    13: (118,131,131,255) #768383FF srgba(118,131,131,1)
    15726: (123,123,123,255) #7B7B7BFF srgba(123,123,123,1)
    15: (123,138,138,255) #7B8A8AFF srgba(123,138,138,1)
    15: (124,131,131,255) #7C8383FF srgba(124,131,131,1)
    2: (127,145,145,255) #7F9191FF srgba(127,145,145,1)
    12469: (131,131,131,255) #838383FF srgba(131,131,131,1)
    33: (132,140,140,255) #848C8CFF srgba(132,140,140,1)
    11: (133,147,147,255) #859393FF srgba(133,147,147,1)
    13: (133,154,154,255) #859A9AFF srgba(133,154,154,1)
    13128: (140,140,140,255) #8C8C8CFF grey55
    93: (140,146,146,255) #8C9292FF srgba(140,146,146,1)
    7: (140,155,155,255) #8C9B9BFF srgba(140,155,155,1)
    4: (140,163,163,255) #8CA3A3FF srgba(140,163,163,1)
    6: (143,171,171,255) #8FABABFF srgba(143,171,171,1)
    15740: (147,147,147,255) #939393FF srgba(147,147,147,1)
    29: (148,155,155,255) #949B9BFF srgba(148,155,155,1)
    5: (148,178,178,255) #94B2B2FF srgba(148,178,178,1)
    44: (149,170,170,255) #95AAAAFF srgba(149,170,170,1)
    19: (150,162,162,255) #96A2A2FF srgba(150,162,162,1)
    3: (151,187,187,255) #97BBBBFF srgba(151,187,187,1)
    274521: (153,153,153,255) #999999FF grey60
    10: (155,187,187,255) #9BBBBBFF srgba(155,187,187,1)
    75: (156,164,164,255) #9CA4A4FF srgba(156,164,164,1)
    30: (156,170,170,255) #9CAAAAFF srgba(156,170,170,1)
    15: (156,179,179,255) #9CB3B3FF srgba(156,179,179,1)
    7: (156,193,193,255) #9CC1C1FF srgba(156,193,193,1)
    15: (161,173,173,255) #A1ADADFF srgba(161,173,173,1)
    101: (163,181,181,255) #A3B5B5FF srgba(163,181,181,1)
    6363: (164,164,164,255) #A4A4A4FF srgba(164,164,164,1)
    34: (164,203,203,255) #A4CBCBFF srgba(164,203,203,1)
    48: (165,189,189,255) #A5BDBDFF srgba(165,189,189,1)
    28: (165,195,195,255) #A5C3C3FF srgba(165,195,195,1)
    10: (166,212,212,255) #A6D4D4FF srgba(166,212,212,1)
    12: (169,196,196,255) #A9C4C4FF srgba(169,196,196,1)
    10850: (170,170,170,255) #AAAAAAFF srgba(170,170,170,1)
    23: (172,204,204,255) #ACCCCCFF srgba(172,204,204,1)
    28: (172,212,212,255) #ACD4D4FF srgba(172,212,212,1)
    39: (172,218,218,255) #ACDADAFF srgba(172,218,218,1)
    12: (174,225,225,255) #AEE1E1FF srgba(174,225,225,1)
    30: (176,214,214,255) #B0D6D6FF srgba(176,214,214,1)
    36: (178,220,220,255) #B2DCDCFF srgba(178,220,220,1)
    76: (180,228,228,255) #B4E4E4FF srgba(180,228,228,1)
    28: (181,234,234,255) #B5EAEAFF srgba(181,234,234,1)
    41: (183,241,241,255) #B7F1F1FF srgba(183,241,241,1)
    37: (184,237,237,255) #B8EDEDFF srgba(184,237,237,1)
    62: (187,244,244,255) #BBF4F4FF srgba(187,244,244,1)
    130392: (191,255,255,255) #BFFFFFFF srgba(191,255,255,1)
  Colormap entries: 64
  Colormap:
    0: (0,0,0,0) #00000000 none
...
    19: (132,140,140,1) #848C8CFF srgba(132,140,140,1)
    20: (140,140,140,1) #8C8C8CFF grey55
    21: (133,147,147,1) #859393FF srgba(133,147,147,1)
    22: (140,146,146,1) #8C9292FF srgba(140,146,146,1)
    23: (133,154,154,1) #859A9AFF srgba(133,154,154,1)
    24: (140,155,155,1) #8C9B9BFF srgba(140,155,155,1)
    25: (147,147,147,1) #939393FF srgba(147,147,147,1)
    26: (148,155,155,1) #949B9BFF srgba(148,155,155,1)
    27: (153,153,153,1) #999999FF grey60
    28: (140,163,163,1) #8CA3A3FF srgba(140,163,163,1)
 ...
```

I think second image can't be readed because:

- It has `Alpha: none   #00000000` (first image has  `Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0)   #FFFFFF00`);
- It has `greyX` entries in colormap;

So, how can i set Alpha as `srgba` instead of `none` and how can I replace `grayX` entries in colormap with `srgba`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the alpha by setting the background colour then setting the alpha to the background... though it would help if we had your image via Dropbox or Google Drive.

```
magick unhappy.gif -background 'srgba(255,255,255,0)' -alpha background happy.gif
```

Comment: Still has alpha: none. Here is an image: https://yadi.sk/d/UeQgMuDo29tgsg (it's PNG, i trying to convert it to GIF)

Comment: Maybe try `magick unhappy.gif -alpha set ...`